# How to recognize urls with similar patterns in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need a way to recognize urls with similar pattern, e.g. a function which returns `true` when matched

```
http://mysite.com/page/123
and
http://mysite.com/page/456
```

or

```
http://mysite.com/?page=123
and
http://mysite.com/?page=456
```

or

```
http://mysite.com/?page=123&param=2
and
http://mysite.com/?page=456&param=3
```

I don't need to check validity of urls here, only find out if the pattern is the same.
I probably need a regular expression for it, but can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: How about `http://mysite.com/?param=2&page=456` - would that count too?

Comment: @MarcGravell If it's rather easy to achieve it would be useful, but not strictly neccessary.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try levenshtein distance
http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein, which is used to find similarity between strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use [a lowest common subsequence algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) and divide by the length of either of the strings. If it's above an arbitrary number, they're common enough.

Comment: What is the best way to find same subsequences in the strings? I guess I could foreach through chars in strings. Is there a better way?

Comment: Look for any implementation out in the wild, it's a common problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not a specific answer, but I feel that if you want this to work well in a generalised sense, you will need to be content-aware, i.e. you need to break each URL into subsections:

- Protocol
- Domain
- Path
- Querystrings

... And process each separately. The level of acceptable fuzziness will control how much you need to break up the URL, but each section would (I feel) need quite specific inspection. The protocol and domain could be straight string matches, but the paths could perhaps be split by '/' and then after basic length checks, the elements could be compared one by one, only comparing items of equal depth (using direct equality or a "change distance" like the Levenshtein distance mentioned earlier). The querystrings could be broken up into dictionaries via a simple split on "&" then by "=", which you could sort and compare however you want. This would also satisfy @MarcGravell's question about reordered querystring parameters.